# Файлы и HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

Что происходит, когда делается `Get` запрос к ссылке за которой какой нибудь файл `.rar` или `.txt` ?

Он начинается записываться в `Response` ?

Как в таком случае определять что там не страница, а какой то иной файл ?

Расширение в ссылке не указано.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы делаете просто `.GetAsync()`, то данные с сайта будут загружен в некий "буфер", это (на сколько я понял) некий участок в оперативной памяти. Если взглянуть на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient), то можно увидеть следующее:

> Если приложение, использующее HttpClient и связанные классы в пространстве имен System.Net.Http, планирует загружать большие объемы данных (50 МБ или более), приложение должно выполнять потоковую передачу этих файлов и не использовать буферизацию по умолчанию. Если используется буферизация по умолчанию, использование памяти клиента будет очень большим, что может привести к значительному снижению производительности.

Не очень будет хорошо, если вы загрузите целый файл в RAM пользователя.

Что касается "Как в таком случае определять что там не страница, а какой то иной файл ?", то тут все довольно просто! Сервер в ответ отдает заголовок `Content-Type`, который содержит в себе [MIME-тип](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2). К примеру простая HTML страница будет иметь `text/html`, 
 а текстовый файл (.txt) `text/plain`. Вот его вам и надо проверить.

---

Исходя из всего этого, мы можем сделать что-то на подобие такого:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "text/html")
    {
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        // делаем что-то с другим типом, например записываем все в текстовый файл.

        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using(var fileStream = File.Create("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь мы при вызове метода `.GetAsync()` задаем не только адрес, но еще и [HttpCompletionOption](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption), это позволит нам прочитать только заголовки от сервера, не загружая контент. Далее достаем `ContentType` и сверяем его. После проверки мы делаем нужные нам действия, загружая данные нужным нам способом.

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо!